# Set git bash_profile PS1 to color branch name when commits have not been pushed or pulled yet

Tags: git, macos, bash, ps1

I'm using this .bash_profile file to know my git status in the command line:

```
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=true

#  Customize BASH PS1 prompt to show current GIT repository and branch.
#  by Mike Stewart - http://MediaDoneRight.com

#  SETUP CONSTANTS
#  Bunch-o-predefined colors.  Makes reading code easier than escape sequences.
#  I don't remember where I found this.  o_O

# Reset
Color_Off="\[\033[0m\]"       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
Black="\[\033[0;30m\]"        # Black
Red="\[\033[0;31m\]"          # Red
Green="\[\033[0;32m\]"        # Green
Yellow="\[\033[0;33m\]"       # Yellow
Blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"         # Blue
Purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"       # Purple
Cyan="\[\033[0;36m\]"         # Cyan
White="\[\033[0;37m\]"        # White

# Bold
BBlack="\[\033[1;30m\]"       # Black
BRed="\[\033[1;31m\]"         # Red
BGreen="\[\033[1;32m\]"       # Green
BYellow="\[\033[1;33m\]"      # Yellow
BBlue="\[\033[1;34m\]"        # Blue
BPurple="\[\033[1;35m\]"      # Purple
BCyan="\[\033[1;36m\]"        # Cyan
BWhite="\[\033[1;37m\]"       # White

# Underline
UBlack="\[\033[4;30m\]"       # Black
URed="\[\033[4;31m\]"         # Red
UGreen="\[\033[4;32m\]"       # Green
UYellow="\[\033[4;33m\]"      # Yellow
UBlue="\[\033[4;34m\]"        # Blue
UPurple="\[\033[4;35m\]"      # Purple
UCyan="\[\033[4;36m\]"        # Cyan
UWhite="\[\033[4;37m\]"       # White

# Background
On_Black="\[\033[40m\]"       # Black
On_Red="\[\033[41m\]"         # Red
On_Green="\[\033[42m\]"       # Green
On_Yellow="\[\033[43m\]"      # Yellow
On_Blue="\[\033[44m\]"        # Blue
On_Purple="\[\033[45m\]"      # Purple
On_Cyan="\[\033[46m\]"        # Cyan
On_White="\[\033[47m\]"       # White

# High Intensty
IBlack="\[\033[0;90m\]"       # Black
IRed="\[\033[0;91m\]"         # Red
IGreen="\[\033[0;92m\]"       # Green
IYellow="\[\033[0;93m\]"      # Yellow
IBlue="\[\033[0;94m\]"        # Blue
IPurple="\[\033[0;95m\]"      # Purple
ICyan="\[\033[0;96m\]"        # Cyan
IWhite="\[\033[0;97m\]"       # White

# Bold High Intensty
BIBlack="\[\033[1;90m\]"      # Black
BIRed="\[\033[1;91m\]"        # Red
BIGreen="\[\033[1;92m\]"      # Green
BIYellow="\[\033[1;93m\]"     # Yellow
BIBlue="\[\033[1;94m\]"       # Blue
BIPurple="\[\033[1;95m\]"     # Purple
BICyan="\[\033[1;96m\]"       # Cyan
BIWhite="\[\033[1;97m\]"      # White

# High Intensty backgrounds
On_IBlack="\[\033[0;100m\]"   # Black
On_IRed="\[\033[0;101m\]"     # Red
On_IGreen="\[\033[0;102m\]"   # Green
On_IYellow="\[\033[0;103m\]"  # Yellow
On_IBlue="\[\033[0;104m\]"    # Blue
On_IPurple="\[\033[10;95m\]"  # Purple
On_ICyan="\[\033[0;106m\]"    # Cyan
On_IWhite="\[\033[0;107m\]"   # White

# Various variables you might want for your PS1 prompt instead
Time12h="\d \t"
Time12a="\@"
PathShort="\w"
PathFull="\W"
NewLine="\n"
Jobs="\j"


prompt_command () {
    # This PS1 snippet was adopted from code for MAC/BSD I saw from: http://allancraig.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=108:ps1-export-command-for-git&catid=45:general&Itemid=96
    # I tweaked it to work on UBUNTU 11.04 & 11.10 plus made it mo' better

    export PS1=$IBlack$Time12h$Color_Off'$(git branch &>/dev/null;\
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
      echo "$(echo `git status` | grep "nothing to commit" > /dev/null 2>&1; \
      if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then \
        # @4 - Clean repository - nothing to commit
        echo "'$Green'"$(__git_ps1 " (%s)"); \
      else \
        # @5 - Changes to working tree
        echo "'$IRed'"$(__git_ps1 " {%s}"); \
      fi) '$BYellow$PathShort$Color_Off'\$ "; \
    else \
      # @2 - Prompt when not in GIT repo
      echo " '$Yellow$PathShort$Color_Off'\$ "; \
    fi)'
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

and it does work when I have uncommitted change, the name of the branch is in red color and when I commit the change it changes to green (see image).

[image: Colors in command line]

I want to have different color when commits have not been pushed yet. Thanks

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use something like oh-my-git: https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git

Comment: To tell you the truth, I didn't like it very much. I like what I have right now, I just want to add an indication that there are un-pushed commits. BTW, oh-my-git doesn't show this information too.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally, I use [Bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) as my prompt. Take a look at this function, it's extracting all of the required information (including ahead/behind) from `git status`: https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/master/themes%2Fbase.theme.bash#L87 - this should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe take a general look at Bash-it - it provides a lot more than that. Some of its themes are similar to what you're using. The [Themes page](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes) shows most of them using screenshots.